# getting all the values in an array except the last one

Tags: php

I have this right now :

```
$s = preg_split('/\s+/', $q);
    $k = end($s);
```

What I want now is to get all the values in the array `$k[]` except the last one, and join them in a new string. So basically if the array was :

```
0 => Hello
1 => World
2 => text
```

I would get `Hello World`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) and [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$k = array( "Hello", "World", "text" );
$sliced = array_slice($k, 0, -1); // array ( "Hello", "World" )
$string = implode(" ", $sliced);  // "Hello World";
```

Comment: Made this to a oneliner, efficient codeline i must say! implode("/", array_slice(explode("/", $serverUrl), 0, -1));

Comment: @EricHerlitz `array_slice` isn't needed. `explode` has a third parameter which makes array_slice obsolete. `implode(' ', explode(' ', 'Hello World text', -1)); // "Hello World"`

Comment: @SeaWorld It's really the same kind of thing. `implode(" ", array_slice(array( "Hello", "World", "text" ), 0, -1));` but sure, if you have a string to start with using explode makes more sense.

Answer (score 7):

If you can modify the array:

```
array_pop($k);
$string = join(' ', $k);
```

---

> array_pop() pops and returns the last value of the array, shortening the array by one element. If array is empty (or is not an array), NULL will be returned.

[Source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

Comment: I like `array_pop` better than `array_slice` because the latter is too general for this specific case.

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_slice($array)` to get a subset of any array.

For everything without the last item I believe it is

```
$return = array_slice($array, 0, count($array)-1, true);
```

Testcase http://codepad.org/fyHHX5Us

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<?php

    $array = array('Hello', 'World', 'text');
    $new_array = array_slice($array,0,-1);
    echo implode(' ',$new_array);

?>
```

[**Example**](http://codepad.org/FX8leBFm)